# code to read text from sd not working

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I am trying to read a file numbersmesa11 from my sd, but I have an error in the final while clause that im not sure what to do, i would appreciate any help! im truly stuck

```
private void readVectorFromFile() {
 InputStreamReader flujo=null;
    BufferedReader lector=null;
    try
    {
        File ruta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File fichero = new File(ruta.getAbsolutePath()+"/BioCasinoStats", "numerosmesa11.txt");                
        flujo= new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fichero));
        lector= new BufferedReader(flujo);
        String texto = lector.readLine();
        while(texto!=null)
        {
            tbTexto.setText(texto);
            texto=lector.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("ivan", "Error al leer fichero desde tarjeta SD");
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if(lector!=null)
                lector.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure all your catch blocks print the stack trace, obtain it from logcat, and post it.

Comment: please post the error you got

Comment: `I have an error in the final while clause` - what error?

Comment: it says tbtexto cannot be resolved

Comment: `it says tbtexto cannot be resolved`. what does it have to do with reading file ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure your Manifest permissions are properly set. To access external storage you should use android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Have look to the documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

If you already done that, try to post the error message to help us identify you issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it's saying that the variable `tbTexto` can't be resolved, check the scope of this variable, or even if this variable exists for this scope.

Also change the catch block to print the stacktraces, a generic catch with no useful information is pointless, as you won't have a clue of which problem cause the expection.